# Claisen-like condensation with acid chloride

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, aldol-reaction, enolate-chemistry

In the Claisen condensation, an ester enolate attacks an ester, with an alkoxide anion leaving subsequently to give a $\beta$-keto ester. Is it possible for a typical enolate of an aldehyde or ketone to react with an acid chloride (acting as the electrophile) to give a $\beta$-keto aldehyde or ketone, with the chloride ion leaving in a similar manner to how the alkoxide leaves in Claisen condensation?

Similarly, could I also extend it to the anhydride as well? Would we observe a similar Claisen-like mechanism?

Comment: It seems that an enamine is able to react in this fashion with an acid chloride: http://chemtube3d.com/Enamine_acylation.html

Comment: I think it is possible.

Comment: Certainly possible if the enolate is generated with a non-nucleophilic base